# How to Run an XMLHttpRequest, Put Result in Session Before Page Loads

Tags: javascript, php

I want to run an XMLHttpRequest to grab information from an API and then use it to populate variables in PHP code that gets executed (without jQuery). While I would like to inject the information after the page loads, that's not possible in this case for various reasons. In essence, we're populating non-HTML PHP code with no CSS ID to select.

I tried creating a Promise and using `then` to inject the results of the API call into session variables, but I discovered that XMLHttpRequest deprecated synchronous requests on the main thread (e.g. you can no longer use `false` for the last parameter in the open function.

E.g.

```
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.myapi.com/api/v1/objects/1.json", false);
```

So, how would I go about setting these variables from XMLHttpRequest before the page is rendered? Is there a good way to do that or is it deprecated for a reason and we need to consider a deeper change?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you'e asking about since you keep mixing languages, like _"PHP code that gets executed (without jquery)"_ and _"non-HTML PHP code with no CSS ID"_. You should also include all the code you've tried together with the expected result and what you're currently getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using synchronous calls was deprecated because is almost always possible to circumvent and it slows page loading and user's experience. Is it really necessary to do it before the page rendering? You can place a loader until the request is done and the callback has the data and then remove it.

Or even better if this happens only on page load PHP can just put the result in the output HTML, if you need to store it for JavaScript use you can echo something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var globalVar = ['stuff'];
</script>
```

You can use it from other scripts, and also use window.globalVar to get the value because it is global.

If it is an api with a private key then it MUST be called by PHP rather than JavaScript, otherwise whoever analyzes the code could gather the API KEY, else if it is public and you don't want to overload the server with this requests the callback method is the way to go: place a loader with an overlay on the rest of the page, when the request is completed, do your calculations and delete or hide loader and overlay elements.